# Why does ceil return 0.000 in the following code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
float i = 2.5;
printf("%d, %f", floor(i), ceil(i));
return 0;
}
```

Although I have used %f specifier in printf() for ceil, it prints 0.000000. Why is this so?

Comment: Because you used %d for the first argument, and so invoked undefined behaviour.

Comment: Try using "%lf" instead of "%f", floor() and ceil() return doubles, not floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of [`floor`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor) is a floating point number (`double` in this case). Passing it with `"%d"` yields *undefined behaviour*.

You need to use the `%f` format specifier. For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
  float i = 2.5;
  printf("%f, %f", floor(i), ceil(i));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

> 2.000000, 3.000000

Comment: So does it effect ceil?

Comment: @Swathi It is *undefined behaviour*. It can affect everything or nothing.